# slice vs normal reference in backbone.js source code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the Backbone.js source code (Collection - "add" method), there is the following line:

```
add: function(models, options) {
  ...
  models = _.isArray(models) ? models.slice() : [models];
```

Why does the author make a copy of the array instead of just

```
add: function(models, options) {
  ...
  models = _.isArray(models) ? models : [models];
```

Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's used to prevent accidental collection modification by altering the array passed to collection constructor somewhere else in the code - might seem unlikely but if it happened it would have been nightmare to debug.

Since arrays are passed as references - altering it in one place would change the models array on the collection as well, but as it would happen outside of collection logics the length of collection etc wouldn't change and the remove model events wouldn't trigger